# std::swap weirdness with G++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, swap

This is a weirdness, where I don't know, if it is with the C++ standard, with my compiler (G++ version 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04, which is the latest long-term support version of Ubuntu) or with me, who doesn't understand ;-)

The code in question is as simple as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::swap
void f(void)
{
    class MyClass { };
    MyClass aa, bb;
    std::swap(aa, bb);          // doesn't compile
}
```

When trying to compile with G++, the compiler yields the following error message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void f()’:
test.cpp:6:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘swap(f()::MyClass&, f()::MyClass&)’
test.cpp:6:21: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/move.h:122:5: note: template<class _Tp> void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/move.h:136:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> void std::swap(_Tp (&)[_Nm], _Tp (&)[_Nm])
```

The surprising result is, that just moving the class definition out of the function makes that code compile fine:

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::swap
class MyClass { };
void f(void)
{
    MyClass aa, bb;
    std::swap(aa, bb);          // compiles fine!
}
```

So is it, that std::swap() is not supposed to work on classes, which are private to functions? Or is this a bug with G++, maybe the specific version of G++ I am using?

Even more puzzling is, that the following does work again, despite MyListClass is also private (but extends an "official" class, for which maybe a specific implementation of swap() exists):

```
#include <algorithm>        // for std::swap
#include <list>             // for std::list
void g(void)
{
    class MyListClass : public std::list<int> { };
    MyListClass aa, bb;
    std::swap(aa, bb);              // compiles fine!
}
```

But just change from objects to pointers, and compiling fails again:

```
#include <algorithm>        // for std::swap
#include <list>             // for std::list
void g(void)
{
    class MyListClass : public std::list<int> { };
    MyListClass aa, bb;
    MyListClass* aap = &aa;
    MyListClass* bbp = &bb;
    std::swap(aap, bbp);    // doesn't compile!
}
```

Of course, in my real application the classes are more complex; I simplified the code as much as possible to still reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are running in C++03 mode, which I believe to be the case, you are not allowed to use a locally defined type in a template. If this is the case you can define your types at the namespace level to make it work, or else you can compile in C++11 mode where it should compile.[*]

In case you wonder why the second case works, the standard does not provide specializations of

```
template <typename T> void swap(T&,T&) // [1]
```

as `std::list` is a template itself and you cannot partially specialize template functions. What it provides is a different base template:

```
template <typename T, typename A> void swap(list<T,A>&,list<T,A>&); // [2]
```

Now as in the previous case, the compiler cannot use your local type with [1], so that is discarded. Then it tries [2], and it finds that it can convert the lvalue of the local type to references to the base `std::list<int>`, and after that conversion [2] is a good candidate. It will then call

```
std::swap(static_cast<std::list<int&>>(aa),static_cast<std::list<int&>>(bb));
```

which does not use a local type, but rather the namespace level `std::list<int>`.

On the other hand, the fact that it compiles does not mean that it does what you want. In particular, if the extended type `MyListClass` adds any new member variables, those will **not** be swapped.

All that being said, and just as a side note: you should not inherit from standard containers, as they were never designed to be inherited from.

[*] Disclaimer: I don't know whether this feature is supported in that particular version of the compiler, you will have to double check.

Comment: According to [the Apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport), GCC supports this since 4.5, so it should be enough to add option `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! Adding -std=c++0x makes things compile fine even with the local classes. Wow, I did not know about the incompatibility with local classes and templates in the older C++ standards.